Compute the probability that a hand of $13$ cards contains the ace and king of at least one suit?

Compute the probability that a hand of $13$ cards contains the ace and
king of at least one suit?

Approach 1
In my first approach I took all 8 cards of aces and kings aside and
then made 4 group each containing ace and king of their own suit.
Then for ace and king from 1 suit $\binom{4}1\binom{44}{11}$, for ace and king from 2 suits $\binom{4}2\binom{44}{9}$, for ace and king from 3 suits $\binom{4}3\binom{44}{7}$ and for ace and king from all 4 suits $\binom{4}4\binom{44}{5}$
$$E = \binom{4}1\binom{44}{11} + \binom{4}2\binom{44}{9} + \binom{4}3\binom{44}{7} + \binom{4}4\binom{44}{5}$$
But my first approach is getting me wrong answer.
Approach 2
In this approach I am using inclusion-exclusion identity
$$E = \binom{4}1\binom{50}{11} -\binom{4}2\binom{48}{9} + \binom{4}3\binom{46}{7} -\binom{4}4\binom{44}{5}$$
I am getting right answer by this approach.
But I can't think of how can any cases remained to be not counted in my first approach.
My question what is difference in my both approaches.

The problem with your first approach is that you assume the king and the ace of a suit must both be included or excluded. You consider only $44$ cards (removing all kings and aces) for the second factor in each term. As a result, the cases where one of the two is included and the other is excluded are not counted.
Also, looks like you need to correct the addition/subtraction signs in the second approach.

Yes I got it I was excluding the cases in which king and ace of same suit as well as only ace or king of other suits are included.
